# How does appjs or node-webkit brings nodejs and CEF together?

Tags: node.js, binding, node-webkit, chromium-embedded, appjs

I am working on a project that requires me to use nodejs filesystem in the CEF browser window that i create. I looked into node-webkit and appjs. I can not use them as there are other business aspects. I also could not find documentation on how are they doing it.

Can somebody explain or provide good source for understanding this ?

Comment: found this for node-webkit: https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/How-node.js-is-integrated-with-chromium.

Answer (score 0):

node-webkit was based on CEF, but later moved to Content Layer of Chromium.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please share some knowledge of combining nodejs and cef in one application ?